# Linking my own ontology with DBPedia's populated ontology

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology, dbpedia, protege

I have this assignment where I have created an rdfs ontology with artists, their songs, their genres, etc using Protégé and populated it with some data. I am now supposed to connect my ontology and it's data with DBPedia's, so that I can SPARQL for my artists' birthdate. I have successfully imported http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ and http://dbpedia.org/property/ into protégé, but I can't find a way to import the data (http://dbpedia.org/resource/).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

DBpedia datasets are stored and available for download here (http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2015-04#h96554-1) but Protégé isn't going to perform well (or at all) when you load a dataset of this size into it.

You may be better downloading various entities by hand such as - http://dbpedia.org/data/Blink-182.ntriples and then loading into Protégé. You can go to any DBPedia page. E.G. http://dbpedia.org/page/Ras_Barker and find download links at the bottom.